# Setting locale in kohana2

Tags: php, internationalization, kohana

How can I change default locale that is defined in locale.php file in Kohana 2.3.4 in runtime?

I use  Kohana::config_set('locale.language', array('en', 'United States')); but after redirect it doesn't work, it gets default value(from locale.php).

Thanks

Comment: Can't you change it in `locale.php`?

Comment: Yes, but when I change the language I want also to change locale. In locale.php I defined $config['language'] = array('no', 'Norsk');

Answer (score 3):

i think you need keep your dynamic settings in session or cookie.
if you nedd i18n, you can use simple code in **bootstrap.php**:

```
I18n::$source = Kohana::config('my.default_language');
I18n::lang(I18n::$source);
```

and in **/application/config/my.php**:

```
$config['languages'] = array(
    'ru' => 'Русский',
    'en' => 'English',
    'pl' => 'Poland',
);
$config['default_language'] = 'en';
```

in **framework/application/classes/controller/template.php**:

```
class Controller_Template extends Kohana_Controller_Template {
    ...
    $session = Session::instance();
    if (Request::current()->param('lang') != null)
    {
        $session->set('lang', Request::current()->param('lang'));
    }
    I18n::lang($session->get('lang', I18n::$source));
```